# Read for loop results into a vector - R language

Tags: r, vector

I am analyzing baseball data for a particular player.  I have a data frame with stats from all of his seasons played.

Below is my code which runs successfully and what it returns to the console.

I want to make one minor change.  Instead of having the code print the times > 40 to the console I would like to read this into a vector.

I tried "Pujols_Over_40 <- c(Pujols$HR[i])" but that doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

```
for(i in 1:nrow(Pujols)){
if(Pujols$HR[i] > 40){
print(Pujols$HR[i])
}
}
[1] 42
[1] 47
[1] 49
[1] 41
[1] 46
[1] 43
```

Comment: please add a tag indicating the code language you're using

Comment: you should add a reproducible example of your data as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
Pujols.count=NULL
for(i in 1:nrow(Pujols)){
 if(Pujols$HR[i] > 40){
  Pujols.count=c(Pujols.count,Pujols$HR[i])
  print(Pujols$HR[i])
 }
}
Pujols.count
```

You can also get rid of the `print` function now.